# VB DataGridWiew

Tags: visual-studio, visual-basic

Я использую datagridview для отображения данных из базы данных, но в ней 22 столбца, необходимо сделать, чтобы у пользователя сохранялось изменение порядка столбцов и их ширина.

Comment: Если хочешь получить хороший ответ, напиши хороший вопрос.

Comment: В Visual Studio на Visual Basic в гриде требуется добавить сохранение ширины и порядка колонок.